# "contains at least one of the following letters" type regex issue

Tags: regex

I'm having a bit of a issue getting an "at least one of certain characters" type regex working.

There are obviously similar questions to my problem but the solutions I am trying are not resolving an incorrect match.

Basically, the regex should match:

**(starts with a forward slash) (has a-z letters but must contain at least an "a", "b" or "d" - this part should be 3 to 4 characters long) (ends in a single digit followed by a slash, the URL need not finish here - can be longer)**

I've got the following but it doesn't work exactly as expected:

```
\/(?=.*[a|b|d])[a-z]{3,4}[\d]\/
```

The above expression incorrectly matches (/ccc1/) of the following expressions (see example at https://regex101.com/r/6ET43K/4/ ):

http://example.com/folder/aaaa/ - no match (no digit at end)

http://example.com/folder/bbb1/ - match (has at least one "b", and digit)

http://example.com/folder/ccc1/ - no match (has neither "a", "b" or "d")

http://example.com/folder/yyd3/ - match (has at least one "d", and digit)

http://example.com/folder/yydd3/ - match (has at least one "d", and digit)

http://example.com/folder/yyddd3/ - no match (too long)

I'd be very grateful for any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might use

```
^.*\/(?=[a-z]{3,4}\d\/)[a-z]*[abd][a-z]*\d\/
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\/` Match until the last `/`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `[a-z]{3,4}\d\/` Assert 3 or 4 times a char a-z followed by 1 digit and `/`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[a-z]*[abd][a-z]*` match at least a single `a` `b` or `d` between optional chars a-z
- `\d\/` Match 1 digit and `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJzojX/1)

Comment: Thanks, this works for me and resolves the false match I had.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, maybe the following will do:

```
^.*\/(?=[a-z]*[abd])[a-z]{3,4}\d\/
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1pZ6I/4)

---

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `.*\/` - Match greedy untill the last forward slash.
- `(?=[a-z]*[abd])` - Positive lookahead with a to match as many alpha chars untill either a, b or d.
- `[a-z]{3,4}\d\/` - Three to four alpha chars, a digit and a literal forward slash.

Comment: Nice ++, you might also change the `[^\/]*` to `[a-z]*` to prevent some backtracking

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks. I updated the answer with your recommendation.

Comment: This works for me too and is a little shorter than the other solution (more elegant? I can't say myself). Thank you.